# Can't install mongo-php-driver on OS X 10.11

Tags: php, mongodb, file-permissions, php-mongodb, osx-elcapitan

I've read through all the similar Stack Overflow questions - nothing addresses my specific issue. I'm running OS X 10.11 (El Capitan).

I've cloned the [mongo-php-drive repo](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver) and these commands succeed:

```
phpize
./configure
make
```

But `sudo make install` fails:

```
(master) ~/tmp/mongo-php-driver
$ sudo make install
Installing shared extensions:     /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/
cp: /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/#INST@39898#: Operation not permitted
make: *** [install-modules] Error 1
```

I understand that it is a permissions issue but I don't know how to safely fix it. I don't want to loosen the security of something like `/usr/*`.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: When you used `git clone` did you then switch to a stable branch/tag? If not then you are reading off "master" which is certainly unstable. Use `git checkout` to switch to a version which is supported.

Comment: After cloning, I run ``git branch -v``` and the result is ```* master 071165f Merge branch 'v1.6'```. I'm new to ```git``` - doesn't this mean I'm on the latest stable branch (which seems to be be v1.6). How do I switch to the right branch? (thank you for your help!)

Comment: Read up on git, and look on github for the latest release tags ( most likely ) for details on what to switch to. Many questions on here about how to do git checkout for tags.

Comment: I checked out and built v1.6.10 (the latest stable tag) and the results are exactly the same - it can't install to ```/usr/lib/php/extensions/``` due to a permission problem. Again, I'd like to know the right/safe way to change the directory permissions so that ```make install``` can succeed.

Comment: I've successfully re-enabled mcrypt by using the technique found at the following link (placing the extension in un-SIP-protected `/usr/local`). I'd be curious if it also works with mongo (I don't see why it wouldn't). http://stackoverflow.com/a/36991283/728053

Answer (score 20):

The problem was due to OS X 10.11 El Capitan's [Rootless feature](https://www.quora.com/Can-someone-elaborate-on-the-OS-X-10-11-feature-called-Rootless). To be able to install the extension into `/usr/lib/php/*` I had to temporarily disable the feature ([instructions](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-turn-off-the-rootless-in-OS-X-El-Capitan-10-11?share=1) - please remember to re-enable it afterwards).

Answer (score 6):

press cmd+r when booting up. Then go into utilities > terminal and type the following commands:

```
csrutil disable
reboot
```

don't forget to enable it .