# Error in mcrypt after upgrading into El Capitan OS

Tags: apache, mcrypt, osx-elcapitan

I just upgraded my OS into El Capitan. I had to do some changes in my apache configurations to make everything works as it did before.

Thanks for - http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-working-on-osx-10-11-el-capitan/

One thing that is not working for me is the Mcrypt extension. Anyone knows how to update it to make it work?

Comment: you can follow this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31879056/cant-install-mongo-php-driver-on-os-x-10-11?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

Can be a problem related to the new [System Integrity Protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection) or "SIP"?
Maybe could be helpful to check permission on the /usr folder and change them as needed.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to El Capitan, mcrypt.so has been moved from

/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212

to

/Library/SystemMigration/History/Migration-(UUID)/QuarantineRoot/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/mcrypt.so

To be able to copy back the moved file, first, you must disable SIP as described here http://www.howtogeek.com/230424/how-to-disable-system-integrity-protection-on-a-mac-and-why-you-shouldnt

Then copy back the moved mcrypt.so to /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212

Finaly restart Apache

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [Coolest Guides On The Planet](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/install-mcrypt-for-php-on-mac-osx-10-10-yosemite-for-a-development-server/#comment-2450227445)'s separate page for mcrypt they suggest disabling SIP. But there's a way to get around that. Follow the guide as normal (skipping the SIP part) and after running `/usr/bin/phpize` you can overide the extensions directory `make` is using.

First create a new home for your php extensions:

```
mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/php/extensions
```

Then run:

```
./configure

make

sudo make EXTENSION_DIR='/usr/local/lib/php/extensions' install
```

And finally, when you add the extension to your `php.ini` the most straightforward option is to include the full path to the file.

```
extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/mcrypt.so
```

So far this is working for me.

Indirect references:
[Error configuring mcrypt after upgrading to El Capitan (Ask Different)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208815/error-configuring-mcrypt-after-upgrading-to-el-capitan/236950)
[Comment by Jon Gardner that started me on the path](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/install-mcrypt-for-php-on-mac-osx-10-10-yosemite-for-a-development-server/#comment-2450227445)