# PHP, mongo.so failed to write

Tags: php, mongodb, pecl

Any help would be great. I've been stuck on this for hours. I'm trying to install Mongo to work with PHP on a Mac. I have Pear/pecl installed and working. When I call `sudo pecl install mongo`, everything looks like it's compiling/building successfully, but at the end I get this message.

> Build process completed successfully Installing
>   '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/mongo.so' ERROR:
>   failed to write
>   /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/mongo.so
>   (copy(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/mongo.so):
>   failed to open stream: Operation not permitted)

And the mongo.so never gets written. Can someone help? I'm using MAMP on Mac OSX El Capitan.

Comment: Try running `sudo su` first, then run the command.

Comment: negative, sudo su did not work. Still getting the failed to write

Comment: This solved the same issue I had . http://stackoverflow.com/a/31884146 . Hope it helps

Comment: @iveedee This is the correct, thanks so much for you help. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Robert has solved this problem in this answer.
[stackoverflow.com/a/31884146](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31884146)
.

Basically the issue is the El Capitan's Rootless feature. Its needs to be disabled in recovery mode, perform the pecl install and that enable it back again .

For some reason , pecl did not install it into my php extensions directly so, I  had to copy the mongo extension pecl generated from the local library to my php extension folder xampp files for it to work

Answer (score 3):

**I've solved this problem by changing `extension_dir` in `php.ini`.**

Create a local extension dir and copy your existing extensions into

```
mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/php/extensions
cp /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/* /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/
```

Update your `php.ini`, change the `extension_dir` and enable mongo:

```
extension_dir = "/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/"
extension=mongo.so
```

Now the extension dir is writeable you can copy the `mongo.so` there.

---

Here's how to compile a mongo.so

```
wget http://pecl.php.net/get/mongo
tar xzvf mongo
cd mongo-1.6.12
phpize
./configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config --with-mongo-sasl=no
make
```

You can find the compiled library in .libs folder: `.libs/mongo.so`
Copy it to extensions dir

```
cp .libs/mongo.so /usr/local/bin/php/extensions/
```

Finally, you can check whether it's working or not, by typing `php -m | grep mongo` in the command line.

Comment: This worked great on the MacOS where System Integrity Protection (SIP) prevents prevents modifying this directory easily. Thanks!

Comment: I think you meant: `cp .libs/mongo.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions` ("lib", not "bin")